# How to customize Grails Spring Security Core 2 login / logout controller and views?

Tags: spring, grails, spring-security

I am using the new Grails Spring Security Core 2.0 plugin and am wondering how i can customize the login view and the LoginController/LogoutController?

The previous versions of the plugin generated these files but now it seems that I have to copy them from the plugin to my project. Is this the correct approach?

And if so, can I put the copied controllers and views into another package then the original ones. IntelliJ seems to dislike having the same artifacts in the same package.

Comment: Did this work for you? I copied `LogoutController.groovy` to `controllers\grails\plugin\springsecurity\LogoutController.groovy` but changes made are not picked up. I think it still uses the plugins controller.

Answer (score 5):

By default in version 2.0 logouts are only allowed via POST requests. To change this to allow GET requests add the following to your Config.groovy file.

```
grails.plugin.springsecurity.logout.postOnly = false
```

Once you have that set you can link directly to logout controller in order to logout

```
<g:link controller="logout">logout</g:link>
```

If you want to find more info on what else was changed in version 2 look to the [What's New in Version 2.0](http://grails-plugins.github.io/grails-spring-security-core/guide/newInV2.html) documentation

Answer (score 2):

Another option would be to use a [remote link](http://grails.org/doc/latest/ref/Tags/remoteLink.html) which by default uses the "post" method

```
    <g:remoteLink class="logout" controller="logout">${message(code: 'springSecurity.logout.link')}</g:remoteLink>
```

Comment: Wouldn't you need to set the `asynchronous` attribute to `false` to actually make the link change the current location of the browser?

Answer (score 1):

I don't think any of the above answers actually answer the question.

If you want to override the controllers and the views in your web-app then yes copy them up into your web-app. You can even give them a different package hierarchy if you wish as the spring-security-core plugin seems to reference them by URL and yours would replace them.

This works because controllers and views declared in the main web-app take precedence over those that are in the plugins.

However if you are doing this in another plugin thats when things get a bit tricky. [See this questiona and answer for a solution to that problem](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24825843/overwrite-a-plugin-gsp-and-controller-within-another-plugin)

Comment: Thanks for adding this answer!!