# Why should spring postOnly be false for Logout to work?

Tags: grails, spring-security

what does postOnly mean in below property

```
grails.plugin.springsecurity.logout.postOnly=false?
```

Why should it be false for Logout to work? Tried making the logout feature work by making it true. But it did not work. What is the reason behind making it false?

Answer (score 3):

For starters, please read the plugin documentation - the 2.x docs are [here](https://grails-plugins.github.io/grails-spring-security-core/v2/) and the 3.x docs are [here](https://grails-plugins.github.io/grails-spring-security-core/v2/).

The plugin defaults to requiring a POST request to logout, but using the config setting you reference you can make your application more convenient to use but less secure by allowing GET or POST requests.

GET requests (e.g. regular links) are supposed to be for actions that read data. A strict REST API requires that GET requests be read-only and also idempotent, but obviously in a regular web app this is too strict. But in general it's best to use links and GET requests to request information, and POST/PUT/DELETE/etc. requests to make changes.

If you include a logout link that uses GET to make the request, it's possible for someone using XSS or similar attacks to trick your browser into logging you out. This isn't a severe vulnerability and requiring POST doesn't make it significantly harder for an attacker but it does raise the bar.

With the default configuration all you need to do is replace a logout link with a simple form that POSTs to that same url (and you can optionally use CSS to style the submit button like a link if you want). If you're comfortable with allowing users to logout with a GET request, change the setting to false and any request to that url will work.

Answer (score 0):

Once you make it true as below

```
grails.plugin.springsecurity.logout.postOnly=true
```

the request method type should be POST only i.e. you can't use GET method.
So, change the logout call to POST type in this case.

You may also look at [How to customize Grails Spring Security Core 2 login / logout controller and views?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20002335/how-to-customize-grails-spring-security-core-2-login-logout-controller-and-vie)

Answer (score 0):

By default Spring Security requires logout to use a POST request to provide [CSRF protection](http://docs.spring.io/spring-security/site/docs/current/apidocs/org/springframework/security/config/annotation/web/configurers/LogoutConfigurer.html#logoutUrl(java.lang.String)). For more on CSRF see [Wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cross-site_request_forgery).

Answer (score 0):

> what does postOnly mean in below property

I means you grails will only logout a user if you send a POST request to the logout url.

> Why should it be false for Logout to work?

It's mainly for [CSRF](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cross-site_request_forgery) protection.

> It is considered best practice to use an HTTP POST on any action that
>   changes state (i.e. log out) to protect against CSRF attacks. If you
>   really want to use an HTTP GET, you can use logoutRequestMatcher(new
>   AntPathRequestMatcher(logoutUrl, "GET"));

Additionally, modern browsers like chrome will ***preload links in a page before the user tries to access them*** to make them fast. This means if you make your logout link accept GET requests, chrome might log you out even if you don't want to.